# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147024809

Tags: sql-server

I created a new email profile with the super admin and I configured the smtp.

Then when I execute this query:

```
   exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @profile_name ='admin_mail',
   @recipients = 'firstname.lastname@email.com',
   @execute_query_database = 'DashboardPowerBi',
   @query = 'select top 20 from Client_1',
   @subject= 'Liste des clients',
   @body_format ='HTML',
   @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

I get this error:

Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147024809

Comment: -2147024809 is 0x80070057, `COR_E_ARGUMENT`, which corresponds to .NET code throwing an `ArgumentException`. Unfortunately this in itself is fairly useless for diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the query is incorrect.  You need to specify which columns you are selecting

```
@query = 'select top 20 * from Client_1',
```

But rather than using '*', actually list the columns you want.

Answer (score 8):

Recently i had an issue related with this, the solution here was to fully qualified the DATABASE + SCHEMA_NAME + TABLE_NAME ('select * from sales..sales_month'), even if you're in the same database.

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error message.   It ended up being I didn't have the database tables fully qualified in the query.      database.schema.tablename        I only had the tablename.

While searching, others had this error because the file attachment was too large.
You can change that in SSMS -  Management - Database Mail

Answer (score 1):

In my case, After I had tested the query and encapsulated in a string, I had forgotten to update...

```
'' AS Blank
```

to

```
'''' AS Blank
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with the directly passing query in `@qry`.

Try to insert the record to be attached in Global TempTable (##Temp) and try to use that select script with specified column names. Like Below

```sql
DECLARE @qry varchar(8000) = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT 
Column1,
Column2
From ##TEMPEMAIL
    SET NOCOUNT OFF'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you could not have brackets around your FQDN, so change this

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT field1, field2, etc FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[Table1]'
```

to this instead.

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT field1, field2, etc FROM DBNAME.dbo.Table1'
```